# How to run a makefile - Python - Speciteller

Tags: python, makefile, nlp, anaconda

I have a large database of text which i want to analyze on it's sentence specificity. I want to use the tool 'Speciteller' for that, using Python. Link to the tool:
https://github.com/wjko2/Domain-Agnostic-Sentence-Specificity-Prediction/tree/master/python

One of the dependencies is to make sure to have liblinear.so. in the python/ directory. If not, i can execute a makefile - 'type make in /python' . I opened my Anaconda Prompt to execute this command,  but it doesn't work. It says it is not recognized as a command, operable program or batch file.

I have already been looking how to specifically execute makefiles in Python, but i have a hard time finding the answer. Does anyone has some advice?

Note: i am still a beginner concerning Python.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Bump - anyone has any idea?

Edit: Operating on a Windows system

Comment: Could you add what operating system you use ? Windows, Linux, MacOS ?

Comment: Just made an edit: windows system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime this problem has been solved. A new update was released and additional code was provided to run it in Python smoothly. See the following repository:

https://github.com/wjko2/Domain-Agnostic-Sentence-Specificity-Prediction

Answer (score 0):

A Makefile is a way to  describe to a computer the steps of the compilation process of a program. To use a Makefile, on an Unix-like system (Linux, MacOS, etc.) one need to have the program `make` installed on their computer, and then, in a unix-shell (and not powershell like the anaconda prompt), run the command `make`.

However Windows does not know natively how to process those files, as the program `make` is not available by default on Windows. You can use a tool like [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) that let you run command designed for GNU/Linux on Windows. (I recommend installing Ubuntu 18.04). Going this route means that you will probably need to reinstall anaconda inside WSL though.